# Strong Parameters not allowing params through?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Here's the problem I've been working on for the last few days:

I have task and completed_task models:

```
class Task < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :user
  has_many :completed_tasks   
end

class CompletedTask < ActiveRecord::Base
  belongs_to :task 
end
```

I have a form that says:

```
<% @tasks.each do |task| %>
  <td><%= link_to task.description, task_path(task)  %></td>
  <td><%= task.user.first_name %></td>
  <td><%= task.value %></td>
  <td><%= task.task_type %></td>
  <td><%= task.frequency %></td
  <td><%= task.active %></td>
  <td><%= task.due_by %></td>
  <%= button_to "Task Completed", new_completed_task_path(:completed =>[:task_id =>
  task.id, :task_value => task.value}) %>         
<%end%>
```

In my completed_task_controller, I have:

```
def new
  @completed_task = CompletedTask.new(params[:completed]) 
end

def create
  @completed_task = CompletedTask.new(completed_task_params)
end
```

When I click on the button to complete a task, I want it to create a record in the completed_tasks table but the params from the parent table are not flowing from the new action to the create action.  I'm guessing it has to do with the strong parameters which I have set as:

```
private
def set_completed_task
  @completed_task = CompletedTask.find(params[:id])
end

def completed_task_params
 params.require(:completed_task).permit(:task_id, :task_value)    
end
```

Here is the error I am getting:

```
ActiveModel::ForbiddenAttributesError
Extracted source (around line #19):

def new
  @completed_task = CompletedTask.new(params[:completed])
end
```

Any ideas???

Comment: Isn't it supposed to be `@completed_task = CompletedTask.new(params[:completed_task])`? Or may be it should be just `@completed_task = CompletedTask.new`.

Comment: I tried both of those and got: Undefined method `new' for nil:NilClass

Comment: Do you placed it in the `new` action or somewhere else?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you call the `new` method, at that point nothing has been returned from the form (it hasn't even been dsiplayed, yet)

You should just do

```
def new
  @completed_task = CompletedTask.new
end
```

When the form is returned, then the `create` method would typically do

```
def create
  @completed_task = CompletedTask.new(completed_task_params)
  if @completed_task.save
    # stuff to do when the record is saved, maybe redirect to show page or index
  else
    # stuff to do if record is not saved... probably redisplay new format with errors
  end  
end
```

EDIT: to clarify, the method `completed_task_params` (which you correctly coded) essentially flags the form attributes as acceptable.  Had you done `CompletedTask.new(params[:completed_task])` strong parameters would've been unhappy as the attributes weren't flagged as permitted.

Comment: I would note here, the relevant part is that when you call completed_task_params, it returns a copy of the params hash which has been marked as "permitted", which is what allows update without a `ForbiddenAttributesError`

Comment: @ABMagil, good point and more directly addresses the question, I'll edit my answer.

Comment: @DougW, if the answer sucessfully fixes your problem, be sure to mark it as accepted (the checkbox underneath its score)